# NoSuchElementException when using Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

So I am trying to access the website and I want the program to apply some filters for me via click. Although when I try to use the function find_element_by_xpath it says that this function is depreciated. Can someone help me ? Also the website is kind of weird because it is more like a dashboard than a website and so I dont know how precise xpath will work. thank you all so much in advance

Comment: You should wait for `filtro-04` to become visible before clicking. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait

Answer (score 0):

The Solution For this problem is :

using the new feature `find_element()`
include this import too

```
from  selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

this is an example :

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("quiz_button")
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "quiz_button")
```

please see this selenium documentation : https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html

Comment: Question appears to be searching for more than just a CSS class

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="filtro-04"]/div/article/div[1]/div/div/qv- 
filterpane/div/div/div/div[2]/span').click()
```

Due to Depreciation Warning use the updated By method

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="filtro-04"]/div/article/div[1]/div/div/qv- 
    filterpane/div/div/div/div[2]/span').click()
```

From there due to page loading.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filtro-04"]/div/article/div[1]/div/div/qv-filterpane/div/div/div/div[2]/span'))).click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: How will `no such element` be fixed by using a different function that does the same thing?

Comment: It's just page loading try the new function below.

Comment: Hey Arundeep, thank you for your reply it is kind of not working for me, I applied the code you provided me and its only clicking "really quick" if this makes sense and then disappearing. If it doesnt take too much of your time could you help me ? I want to select the first type of vaccine shown when I select Type of vaccine and I want to select a date. on this website: https://infoms.saude.gov.br/extensions/DEMAS_C19VAC_Distr/DEMAS_C19VAC_Distr.html. Above I have uploaded a picture. Thank you very much

Comment: ul.qv-listbox >li would be the css selector for the first element.